# Why my subprocess generated by pool.apply_async() always run as MainProcess?

Tags: python

My env is Python2.7.I am very fuzzed,I run my apply_async(test_func),and I let the test_func print the current process_name.As like:

```
q = Queue(maxsize=20) #multiprocessing.Queue

def test_func(queue):
    print 'Process'
    print multiprocessing.current_process()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    for i in xrange(3):
        pool.apply_async(test_func(q,))
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if q.empty():
            break
        print 'Main Process Monitoring'
        print multiprocessing.current_process()
```

The code has no syntax error,and the terminal always print `<MainProcess>`

If I change `pool.apply_async(test_func,(q,))(add a comma)`,it couldn't get into the `test_func`,just like simply finish for loop,and it just print `'Main Process Monitoring' <MainProcess>`..

So I can't understand why `apply_async()` can't work normally and when it work,it runs as `MainProcess`,and I have tried `pool.close(),pool.join()`.Nothing change.
If anyone can help.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `test_func` function has no `return` statement, so it returns `None`:

```
def test_func(queue):
    print 'Process'
    print multiprocessing.current_process()
```

Inserting this into an interactive Python:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> x = test_func(None)
Process
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
>>> print x
None
```

This means that:

```
    pool.apply_async(test_func(q,))
```

calls `test_func` with argument `(q,)`, which returns `None`; then you pass `None` to `pool.apply_async`.

[The `multiprocessing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) describes `apply_async` as invoking its first argument a la `apply`, but asynchronously, i.e., without waiting for its result.  Let's try `apply(None)` interactively, just to see what that does:

```
>>> apply(none)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

So we might expect `apply_async` to raise a TypeError—and in fact, that *is* what it does, but the error is deferred until we try to get the result:

```
>>> pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
>>> pool.apply_async(None)
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x801b27510>
```

Let's grab this ApplyResult object so we can use and inspect it (the special name `_` holds the most recent value returned during the interaction):

```
>>> x = _
```

Now we can see if the asynchronous apply has a result for us:

```
>>> x.ready()
True
```

It does!  (We can call `x.wait()` to wait for it if not, but since it's ready now, let's press on.)  Is the result a regular value, or an exception?

```
>>> x.successful()
False
```

Ah, the result is an exception.  Let's get the exception:

```
>>> x.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

And there we have the answer: passing `None` to `apply_async` spins off the execution of the function `None` (which is not a function after all), and once we collect the final result, that result is the exception we would expect.

> If I change `pool.apply_async(test_func,(q,))` (add a comma), it couldn't get into the `test_func` ...

Let's try something like that in the interactive interpreter.  I don't have a `q` but since `test_func` does not actually use its arguments, we're OK here with passing None:

```
>>> x = pool.apply_async(test_func, (None,))
>>> Process
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
```

This output is a bit messy but it sure looks like it worked.  Let's see if `x` has a result, and whether it's successful, and what its result is:

```
x.ready()
True
>>> x.successful()
True
>>> x.get()
>>>
```

(the first `>>>` prompt seems to be missing, but it's really just been printed-over by the things printed in `test_func`).  There is a successful value, but since it's None, the interpreter did not print anything here—we'd have to have done `print x.get()` to see it.

In other words, if you're going to use `apply_async` you must (1) save the spun-off "pending result" somewhere, and then (2) use `.get()` to actually *retrieve* that result.  You also need to return something from your function.

Meanwhile this loop:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if q.empty():
        break
    print 'Main Process Monitoring'
    print multiprocessing.current_process()
```

never runs all the way through once, because your queue object `q` *is* empty at the time you test it, so you immediately `break` out of it.

Comment: Yeah,my queue object `q` is not empty,I omit some steps.My program does not need the subprocess to return results(except check),and I must add return statement?But I can run normally without that after your suggestioon.

Comment: Well, if your real function has no useful return value, you don't need to collect it, but you probably still need to wait for it to complete.  But if you've stripped out the data that goes into the Queue object `q`, perhaps you have stripped out some other real problem(s).

Comment: Thanks,I found use that return value and .get() help a lot.But `result = pool.apply_async(test_func, (q))` 'print result.get()`,that will raise exception 'Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`. If I do it like `p = Process(target=test_func, args=(q,))`,it work normally.Do

Comment: Oh,I fix it,it needs Manager().Queue() object........Thanks a lot,your suggestions are very helpful!

Comment: I have another question, if pass `q` object to `test_func`, its process name is subProcess, and the program must wait for that subProcess. I mean even if I use several `apply_async` to start new subProcess,  it will block at the first subProcess.

Comment: The way that `Pool` works is that each `apply_async` spun off *before* waiting for a previous `apply_async` will create a new worker process *if it has not reached its limit*. Otherwise it will automatically wait for one to finish and be ready for another call. If your function (or functions) wait *internally* (e.g., on data from a `Queue`), they will not finish, and the `Pool` will wait forever for them.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally,I know that I should use `apply_async(test_func, (i,))`,and this is a mistake for me.

But what very odd is that,when I usse `apply_async(test_func, (q,))`,it will not work.the `q` is multiprocessing.Queue().If I remove it or substitute for any other except Queue object,it will work(print subprocess normally)

I don't know whether the Queue has some errors or something else raise...

Does any one knows that?Thanks a lot!